# Why are loops using mysql_fetch_array affected by a previous mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, loops

I performed a query and captured the results in a variable called `$raw_results`;

I then have the following:

```
$record_set = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($record_set);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<hr />";
```

And right below it, I have:

```
while ($record_set = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
{
echo "<pre>";
print_r($record_set);
echo "</pre>";
}
```

I'm surprised (and confused) that the `while loop` starts at `record #2 in the array` instead of `record #1`.

If I remove the block above the loop, then the loop displays `record #1` as I originally expected.

Why is the loop being affected by the block above it?

Thanks in advance for taking the time.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `mysql_fetch_array()` advances the record pointer in the result resource `$raw_results`.  So the initial call has already advanced it to the second record. The next call, whether in a loop or singly, will retrieve the next (second) row.

To rewind it back to the first record, you can use [`mysql_data_seek()`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-data-seek.php):

```
mysql_data_seek($raw_results, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the first time you use `mysql_fetch_array` it returns the first row and moves the pointer to the next row.